# I'm trying to simply make a script that will collect the cookies through my login and then print the names of them out

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, request

The issue I'm running into is when it gets the cookies of the website it gets the cookies as if the account isnt logged in it gets the unlogged in home page cookies instead of the cookies that the logged in user would have

Code:

```
import requests
import http.cookiejar


with requests.Session() as req:
    req.get ('http://mywebsite.com/)
    req.cookies['Cookie names'] = http.cookies
    print (req.cookies)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You're missing a ```'``` at the end of the url.    As far as I can tell,  you using req as is, you haven't provided any login credentials to your request, so you're naturally getting cookies as if the person was not logged in.

Comment: Hey the ' was a accidental delete. The issue is the program needs to be ran then get the name cookie without having login creds, something similar to if the website is open then check for the name cookie as more than likely they will be logged in.